# Cannot change background color of matplotlib Figure (when saving as image)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The actual problem that I have, is that - in the code I'm working on: when I try to save the plot image, I get the plot background in the image as fully transparent, so it looks like this in an image viewer (here `eom`, Mate's version of `eog`):

[image: transparent background]

I would like to have the background color to be fully opaque white, instead.

This seems to have been a problem often, e.g.:

- [Matplotlib figure facecolor alpha while saving (background color, transparency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542610/matplotlib-figure-facecolor-alpha-while-saving-background-color-transparency)
- [Matplotlib savefig background always transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204749/matplotlib-savefig-background-always-transparent)
- [Set background color behind the image in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577608/set-background-color-behind-the-image-in-matplotlib)
- https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-change-the-color-background-of-a-matplotlib-figure-/

Anyways, one problem is that I *cannot* reproduce this with a minimal example. In my code, essentially I have to convert the figure to an image first, then process that image, then finally save it. So I tried making a minimal example, with a conversion to image data first, which is then being saved:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
print(f"{mpl.__version__}")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import io

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

subplotpars = dict(left = 0.05, right=0.99, top=0.89, wspace=0.1)
gss = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=(2, 1), **subplotpars),

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gss[0]
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])

ax.plot(t, s, color=(0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6))

print(f"{fig.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.get_alpha()=}")
print(f"{fig.patch.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.patch.get_alpha()=}")

with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    fig.savefig(buf, dpi=120, format="png")
    buf.seek(0)
    fig_rgba = plt.imread(buf)

plt.imsave('example_io.png', fig_rgba, dpi=120)
```

... and this code prints this for me:

```
3.5.1
fig.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fig.get_alpha()=None
fig.patch.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fig.patch.get_alpha()=None
```

... and tells me that I have matplotlib 3.5.1, and that the figure background color is defined as RGBA, although with alpha channel set to 1 (opaque). Ultimately, the image that is output by this code, for me, is with fully opaque white background - so this code does not demonstrate the problem.

So, while I cannot reconstruct my problem as a minimal example - I managed to narrow down the problem in my actual code, in this snippet:

```py
        # ... time to save as image:

        print(f"A {self.fig.get_facecolor()=}, {self.fig.get_alpha()=}")
        print(f"A {self.fig.patch.get_facecolor()=}, {self.fig.patch.get_alpha()=}")

        orig_figcol = self.fig.get_facecolor()
        orig_figpatchcol = self.fig.patch.get_facecolor()
        self.fig.set_facecolor( (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) ) # calls patch.set_facecolor anyway
        self.fig.patch.set_facecolor( (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) )
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        print(f"B {self.fig.get_facecolor()=}, {self.fig.get_alpha()=}")
        print(f"B {self.fig.patch.get_facecolor()=}, {self.fig.patch.get_alpha()=}")

        with io.BytesIO() as buf:
        # ...
```

When this section in the code is ran, I get a printout:

```
A self.fig.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0), self.fig.get_alpha()=None
A self.fig.patch.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0), self.fig.patch.get_alpha()=0
B self.fig.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0), self.fig.get_alpha()=None
B self.fig.patch.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0), self.fig.patch.get_alpha()=0
```

So, unlike the basic example above, the starting background color of the plot, as RGBA, is (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0) - that is to say, alpha channel is zero (so no surprise the background is transparent).

**However**, I do call `set_facecolor` right after, with an RGBA color where alpha is 1, and I even call `.draw()`, to hopefully trigger a refresh/redraw -- but **regardless**, when try to get the same facecolor I just previously set, it *still* returns the old color value, where alpha was 0!

So, essentially, the way I see this is: something does not let me change the Figure background color, right before I want to save the figure as an image.

Under what circumstances would matplotlib *not* let me change the image background - and ultimately, how can I change the plot figure background color, right before I save the figure as image (or export it as image data, that is, pixels)?

Comment: See [Matplotlib figure facecolor (background color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804005/matplotlib-figure-facecolor-background-color).  Matplotlib deliberately looks at the background color set in `savefig`, ignoring the figure's color. The suggested workaround is `fig.savefig('whatever.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor='none') `

Comment: Thanks, @JohanC - as the post shows, I cannot change `facecolor` of `fig` to a color that has alpha=1, so entering `facecolor=fig.get_facecolor()` will not do much. Just now I also tried explicitly `fig.savefig('whatever.png', facecolor=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)...` - but that did not work either.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC - what I mean with "*...but that did not work either*" was that I got an image with transparent background again, even if I explicitly set an RGBA color of (1,1,1,1) which has an alpha of 1 (which should create an opaque background, not transparent). "Are you sure the resulting png file had a transparent background" - yes, I see the checkered background as in the OP image. " Which backend are you using" - for me `mpl.get_backend()` says `'TkAgg'`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution - this required some debugging and drilling down of code; it turns out, one of the forest of libraries I include in my code, decided to change matplotlib figure properties - so here is a bit of a writeup:

So, after my attempt to use `pdb` to debug this failed ([Inspecting a variable value in other stack frames in pdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011506/inspecting-a-variable-value-in-other-stack-frames-in-pdb)), I found [How do you watch a variable in pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668979/how-do-you-watch-a-variable-in-pdb/65242396#65242396) - which recommended the [watchpoints](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/watchpoints) library.

So basically, after my figure init (`self.fig = plt.figure(...`), I did:

```
watch(self.fig.patch._facecolor)
```

... and ran the code; and finally I got something like this in the terminal printout:

```
====== Watchpoints Triggered ======
Call Stack (most recent call last):
...
>   figure.patch.set_alpha(0)
  set_alpha (~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py:394):
>   self._set_facecolor(self._original_facecolor)
  to_rgba (~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:192):
>   return rgba
self.fig.patch._facecolor:
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
->
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0)
```

So, one of these libraries ended up calling `figure.patch.set_alpha(0)` - which turns out to be a bit nastier than one would deduce from the naming alone; namely, once it is set to 0 - it will *prohibit* entering any other alpha value, whenever you want to set the face color!!! Here is a code that reproduces that, based on the OP code:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
print(f"{mpl.__version__}")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import io

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

subplotpars = dict(left = 0.05, right=0.99, top=0.89, wspace=0.1)
gss = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=(2, 1), **subplotpars),

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gss[0]
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])

ax.plot(t, s, color=(0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6))

print(f"A {fig.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.get_alpha()=}")
print(f"A {fig.patch.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.patch.get_alpha()=}")

fig.patch.set_alpha(0)

print(f"B {fig.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.get_alpha()=}")
print(f"B {fig.patch.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.patch.get_alpha()=}")

fig.patch.set_facecolor( (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0) )

print(f"C {fig.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.get_alpha()=}")
print(f"C {fig.patch.get_facecolor()=}, {fig.patch.get_alpha()=}")

with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    fig.savefig(buf, dpi=120, format="png", facecolor=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    buf.seek(0)
    fig_rgba = plt.imread(buf)

plt.imsave('example_io.png', fig_rgba, dpi=120)
```

This prints:

```
3.5.1
A fig.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fig.get_alpha()=None
A fig.patch.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fig.patch.get_alpha()=None
B fig.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0), fig.get_alpha()=None
B fig.patch.get_facecolor()=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0), fig.patch.get_alpha()=0
C fig.get_facecolor()=(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0), fig.get_alpha()=None
C fig.patch.get_facecolor()=(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0), fig.patch.get_alpha()=0
```

So - with `fig.patch.set_alpha(0)` having ran once, *even* if I set `fig.patch.set_facecolor( (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0) )` afterward (which explicitly sets alpha to 0) - the actual fill color that ends up in the object, *still* has alpha=0 (as printout C shows)!

So if you run that code, you still get transparent background in the image.

The solution turns out to be - just set `fig.patch.set_alpha(1.0)` right before the `fig.savefig` call:

```py
# ...
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    fig.patch.set_alpha(1.0)
    fig.savefig(buf, dpi=120, format="png", facecolor=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    # ...
```

Boy.... Now those were some wasted hours of my life... I wish someone would invent some machines, that you could program ... oh wait